# Modifying the format of RTC values in ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, real-time-clock

I'm trying to pull the AM/PM time from the RTC along with the Year. I want the values printed for AM/PM to be A for AM and B for PM. And all I want printed with the year, is the final digit. I then have the day of the year added afterwards. This is to identify the product's shift it was made on, the year, and the day of the year.

This is what I currently have: "^CFA,57^FWB^FO1181,100^AD^FC%^FD%p%y-%j^FS", and its displaying AM24-0018 or PM24-0018 depending on the shift who created the product. If you have any other ideas that may include using an increment or decrement to achieve the desired outcome, please let me know.